# Nested SQL query with counts and where conditions in Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, count, where-clause

I have the following data in a table `GAontime`. `OrgEinheit` means department and `GALaufzeit` is the throughput time:

```
CREATE TABLE GAontime
    ([Auftragsart] varchar(9), 
     [GAZurueckIST] varchar(23), 
     [GALaufzeit] int, 
     [OrgEinheit] varchar(9), 
     [GAErteilungsJahr] int
    );

INSERT INTO GAontime
    ([Auftragsart], [GAZurueckIST], [GALaufzeit], [OrgEinheit], [GAErteilungsJahr])
VALUES
    ('Gutachten', '2003-10-02 00:00:00.000', 2, 'FE11', 2003),
    ('Gutachten', '2003-10-09 00:00:00.000', 2, 'FE12', 2003),
    ('Gutachten', '2003-11-13 00:00:00.000', 3, 'FE12', 2003),
    ('Gutachten', '2006-12-01 00:00:00.000', 1045, 'FO11', 2004),
    ('Gutachten', '2003-11-18 00:00:00.000', 4, 'FE11', 2003),
    ('Gutachten', '2003-11-25 00:00:00.000', 6, 'FE12', 2003),
    ('Gutachten', '2003-12-11 00:00:00.000', 3, 'FE11', 2003),
    ('Gutachten', '2003-12-10 00:00:00.000', 2, 'FE12', 2003),
    ('Gutachten', '2003-12-19 00:00:00.000', 1, 'FE11', 2003),
    ('Gutachten', '2004-01-08 00:00:00.000', 1, 'FE11', 2004),
    ('Gutachten', '2004-02-25 00:00:00.000', 34, 'FE11', 2004),
    ('Gutachten', '2004-03-19 00:00:00.000', 57, 'FE12', 2004),
    ('Gutachten', '2004-02-25 00:00:00.000', 35, 'FE11', 2004),
    ('Gutachten', '2004-08-12 00:00:00.000', 94, 'FO1', 2004),
    ('Gutachten', '2004-02-05 00:00:00.000', 1, 'FE11', 2004),
    ('Gutachten', '2004-02-12 00:00:00.000', 6, 'FE12', 2004),
    ('Gutachten', '2004-06-18 00:00:00.000', 121, 'FE11', 2004),
    ('Gutachten', '2004-02-25 00:00:00.000', 7, 'FE11', 2004),
    ('Gutachten', '2004-03-05 00:00:00.000', 10, 'FE12', 2004),
    ('Gutachten', '2004-02-25 00:00:00.000', 0, 'FE11', 2004),
    ('Gutachten', '2004-03-19 00:00:00.000', 8, 'FE12', 2004)
;
```

What I want to get ultimately is a table like this:

```
OrgEinheit GAErteilungsJahr TotalNumber NumberFaster22d Percentage
FE11       2003             10          3               0.3
FE11       2004             20          6               0.3
FE12       ...
```

So what I need is to get:

1. The total number of requests for an 'OrgEinheit' in each year
2. The number of requests with a leadtime faster than 22 days
3. The calculated percentage of 1.) + 2.)

For 1.) I managed to get a result with

```
SELECT OrgEinheit, 
COUNT(*) AS Anzahl, GAErteilungsJahr
FROM GAontime
GROUP BY OrgEinheit, GAErteilungsJahr
```

For 2.) I have:

```
SELECT OrgEinheit, Count(*) As Total
FROM GAontime
WHERE (GALaufzeit < 22)
GROUP BY OrgEinheit, GAErteilungsJahr
```

For the rest I am messed up with syntax problems because I want to do this within a single SQL query.

My planned following steps are:

- JOIN tables from 1.) with 2.)
- Do the calculation of the percentage
- Get as a result a table for a database view  (like described in 'What I want')

How can I compose this big SQL query? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (2) is per `OrgEinheit` but *not* per `GAErteilungsJahr`. It is thus likely that the number from (2) is bigger than the number from (1). It doesn't make much sense to calculate a percentage value with these terms.

Comment: Yes, you're right - my mistake. I corrected (2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the 'filter' within the same query by applying a CASE .. WHEN projection and counting the positive matches. You can then apply the percentage calculation without repeating the calculation by using a derived table or a CTE:

```
SELECT OrgEinheit, GAErteilungsJahr, TotalNumber, NumberFaster22d, 
    CAST(NumberFaster22d AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / TotalNumber AS Percentage
FROM
(
    SELECT OrgEinheit, GAErteilungsJahr, COUNT(*) AS TotalNumber, 
           SUM(Case WHEN GALaufzeit < 22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumberFaster22d
    FROM GAontime
    GROUP BY OrgEinheit,GAErteilungsJahr
) x
ORDER BY OrgEinheit,GAErteilungsJahr;
```

Comment: This also works well, thank you. I think the difference compared to JamesZ is that you used a COUNT instead of a 'SUM(1)'. Thank you for the referring also to 'CTE'. I've never heard of this topic before.

Comment: Note that the pseudo table returned as 'x' is called a `derived table` -  isn't a subquery as it returns more than one column. CTE is similar, although placed at the start of the query i.e. `WITH x as (...) SELECT ... FROM x`

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for something like this? Your data and example doesn't really match, but this is made from your attempts:

```
select
  *,
  cast(NumberFaster22d as float) / TotalNumber as Percentage
from
(
  select
    OrgEinheit,
    GAErteilungsJahr,
    sum(1) as TotalNumber,
    sum(case when GALaufzeit < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as NumberFaster22d  
  from
    GAontime
  group by
    OrgEinheit,
    GAErteilungsJahr
) X
order by
  OrgEinheit,
  GAErteilungsJahr
```

The case is used to calculate only rows with value < 22 and the derived table is used to calculate the ratio.

You can test this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5ea0/1)

Comment: Your suggestion works well, thank you! I think the clue is to use 'sum' together with 'case'. I also learnt that the subquery needs a name like the 'X'. I didn't respect this in an earlier attempt. Is 'X' equivalent to 'AS X'?